# How to save php files as .phar or edit source code saved as .phar?

Tags: codeception, phar

I have downloaded Codeception source code (in .phar format), but I need to add same changes there. So, I want to edit this .phar file, but cannot find a solution, how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your own phar by using Robo tool.

It is documented in http://codeception.com/install

1. Clone from GitHub:

   - git clone git@github.com:Codeception/Codeception.git
2. Install dependencies with Composer

   - cd Codeception
   - curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
   - php composer.phar install
3. Make your changes
4. Install Robo

   - wget http://robo.li/robo.phar
5. Build package

   - php robo.phar build:phar

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the tools listed in http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-phar-files.htm#tools to extract and then re-add the file you want to edit.

The `phar` executable shipped with PHP is able to `extract` files and you can `add` the modified file afterwards.